# wit.ai understanding tab is not resulting expected intent roles

Tags: facebook, wit.ai

I am developing an app using wit ai and facebook messenger, everything is working as expected but I am stuck on a expression which is always returning wrong role.

I have added similar expression for that intent but when I test the same sentence it returns wrong role. Please see screenshot attached

Below image shows that expression is properly validated, here mumbai is recognized as wit/location:origin
[image]

But When I test the same expression, it only returns location against mumbai rather than location:origin..

Any help ?
[image]

Comment: why this is voted down ? I read full documentation of wit.ai and did what I can...

Comment: Hi, Wit crew here. It looks like a bug on our side, you're doing things right. I'm have a look at it, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

I checked and your training was stuck for some reason. I just restart it manually and it works now.

[Training Status Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QL5U.png)

Comment: usually validating a new expressions should trigger a re-training

Comment: Ysterday I was training my bot , but it was like stuck and takes 30-40s to train for each validator..Someone told that wit is facing some technical issue...Is there any tool/api/xyz which can train my bot, once I feed all statements.